# Why didn't the Tur discuss traditional Jewish philosophy?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rambam, halacha-theory, jewish-books, tur

Of all classical works of Halacha, only the Rambam has a section dedicated "Hilchos Deos". For example, he begins with the most fundamental Jewish belief, the belief in one G-d, that G-d is the original existence, that He doesn't have a body, etc.

Yet, none of the other classical Jewish Halachic books (such as the Tur, therefore the Shulchan Aruch, etc.) discuss these concepts at length. These concepts are the fundamentals of Judaism. Someone that doesn't believe in them is a heretic (which has practical ramifications for Yayin Nesech etc.)

Why doesn't the Tur discuss these Halachos?

Comment: See his introduction. I think he clearly states all the things he writes that are not really things that about belief, rather about action.

Comment: Also, see the Arukh HaShulchan where he discusses Yesodei HaDat in siman aleph of orach chayim.  He discusses these concepts there as well.

Comment: I assume when you said "Deos" you meant "Yesodei HaTorah"

Comment: Why not provide extensive Bible commentary? Or a treatise on grammar? Or cooking recipes? Because those aren't the subject of the book!

Comment: @mevaqesh because none of those have practical halachic ramifications. Hilchos Deos does.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin If, indeed, your whole questioning is predicated on the assumption that the reason why Rambam writes his lengthy Hilkhot Yesodei HaTorah (not to be confused with Hilkhot De'ot), emphasizing belief in God, etc. is because this can have ramifications on hilkhot yeyn nesekh, (an extremely dubious assumption, for multiple reasons), then consider clarifying that in the question, rather than leaving it as an apparent afterthought in parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

According to what I've been taught, philosophy was the essence of Judaism to the Rambam, so it makes sense that he would treat philosophical issues (practical ones) in the Yad. Indeed quite a bit of Yesode haTorah is metaphysics! Perhaps other Rishonim saw these areas as less intrinsic to halachah.

Comment: Downvoter, y u downvote?

Answer (score 3):

He (they) may not have felt the need, as he was writing for a fully observant audience that may need to reference laws for practical purposes and learning. RaMBa"M may have intended to reach a broader audience.

Compare the different Hakdamoth for clues.

Comment: Have you looked at the respective hakdamoth? What do they say? Do they support your thesis? Threaten it? Consider editing this in.