# Skipped Halachot in the Tur/Shulhan Aruch

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, shulchan-aruch, tur

It seems to me that there are some missing Halachot in Tur/SA. For example, Hilchot Lashon Hara, WeHalchta Bidravaw, and Tamim Tihye. Feel free to add.

Sources aren't necessary.

Why are they missing?

Comment: and your question is....? (I think I know, but please clarify) :)

Comment: Hilkhoth Melakhim uMilhamoth (including laws on naziruth); laws pertaining to the Sanhedrin and its authority.

Comment: If the question is "why", I would venture to say that codes like Mishne Torah which contain a complete system containing all aspects of halakhat Haza"l, codes such as Shulhan Arukh do not. Although I've heard the specific percentage "86%" being the similarity between M"T and S"A, the latter is applicable for life in galut. This is evidenced by the fact, as you pointed out, it lacks some halakhot. However, I would have no idea why that would mean it lacks hilkhoth lashon hara`.

Comment: As @Aman pointed out, I don't think R' Ya'aqob's goal was to codify all of Tora Shebeal Peh the way Rambam did. For example, he left out most of Kodashim, even though there's a whole Seder of Mishnah on it. Your question will only be valid when you clarify what R' Ya'aqob hoped to accomplish with the publication of the Tur, and THEN try to see if certain dinnim aren't there which should be.

Comment: @   yeah, but some are practical?هه ه

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why didn't the Tur discuss traditional Jewish philosophy?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/why-didnt-the-tur-discuss-traditional-jewish-philosophy)

Answer (score 0):

Tamim Tihye is in Yoreh Deah Siman 179 and the other Mitzvos and more are brought in Shulchan Aruch Horav (and other Achronim) in Siman 156. But I don't know why the Tur/SA doesn't mention them.

Comment: SA HaRav isn't SA.