# What does it mean Halachicly: "Hamechaber omitted those Halochos"?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory, shulchan-aruch

There are numerous Halochos that appear in Rambam and even HaTur, and do apply nowadays, but **HaMechaber omitted it completely from Shu"A**, like Hilchot Teshuva, Hilchot שמירת הנפש, Hilchot Deot and many more.

Most of them, as I can see, pertain to human qualities (מידות) and not straight Mitzvot.

What did HaMechaber think leaving those Halochos out of Shu"A and others that agreed on that?

What Halachic status do those Halochos have if he omitted them - are they still obligating Halochos or he didn't see it that way at all?

Comment: Shmirat hanefesh wasn't omitted.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22089 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15675

Answer (score 3):

In his [introduction to the Shulchan Aruch](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A/%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%94) the Mechaber notes that his Shulchan Aruch is a summary of the Beit Yosef, written concisely so that one can review it every 30 days.

> ראיתי אני בלבי, כי טוב ללקוט שושני ספירי אמריו **בדרך קצרה ולשון צח וכולל**, יפה ונעים, **למען תהיה תורת ה' תמימה שגורה בפי כל איש ישראל**. כי כאשר ישאלו לתלמיד חכם דבר הלכה, לא יגמגם בה, אלא יאמר לחכמה אחותי את, כשם שברור לו שאחותו אסורה לו כך יהיה ברור לו כל דין שישאל עליו הלכה למעשה, בהיותו שגור בפיו ספר זה הבנוי לתלפיות, תל שהכל פונים בו, **לחלקו לחלקים שלושים, ללמוד בו בכל יום חלק, ונמצא שבכל חודש הוא חוזר תלמודו**, ויאמר עליו אשרי מי שבא לכאן ותלמודו בידו:

<sup>(As Google translates - hence the stilted style, with some edits)</sup>

> I saw in my heart that it is good to **summarize the best parts of my Sefer in a short way** and to have a clear and beautiful tongue, beautiful and pleasant, s**o that the Torah of the Lord will be fluent in the mouth of all Jews**. When he is asked to learn Torah, he will not stammer it, but he will answer clearly, just as it is clear to him that his sister is forbidden to him, so it will be clear to him that any law will be asked about him in practice. D**ivided into thirty, to study in it every day, thus each month he reviews to his learning**, as per the expression: "Blessed is he who came here and taught him in his hand:

The Halachot you mention are hinted at.

- Teshuva is in Hil. Yom Kippour where he mentions asking for forgiveness from people, getting lashes on Erev YK and saying Viduy.
- Shmirat HaNefesh and Deot are sprinkled throughout Shulchan Aruch, like not doing dangerous things (Y.D. 116 and C.M 427) and avoiding vanity (O.C. 2:6)

Since it's a summary, he doesn't go into the details that he assumes you'll remember.

So, to your questions:

> What did HaMechaber think leaving those Halochos out of Shu"A and others that agreed on that?

**This was done for brevity**, though the Mechaber does not disclose the system he used for deciding what to include and what to exclude.

Many others actually did include many of the omitted Halachot, starting with the Remo and ending with the Mishna Berura.

The end result is what the Mechaber tried to prevent: A volume of Halachot too large to review in 30 days.

> What Halachic status do those Halochos have if he omitted them - are they still obligating Halochos or he didn't see it that way at all?

Because the reason for omitting Halachot is not Halachic but practical, there seems to be **no Halachic significance** to the omissions from the Shulchan Aruch, especially considering that the Mechaber seems to have addressed each (or most) of the *omitted* Halachot in the Bet Yosef on the Tur.

---

The [full introduction](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A/%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%94) reads:

> אודה ה' מאד בפי ובתוך רבים אהללנו ומשירי אהודנו:‏
>
> במה אקדם ה' אכף לאלקי מרום, אשר ממעון קדשו מן השמים הופיע ברוב רחמיו וחסדיו, והשפיע מטובו על שפל אנשים כמוני, לחבר ספר הנותן אמרי שפר, החיבור הגדול שחברתי על הארבעה טורים, אשר קראתיו בית יוסף, אשר כללתי בו כל הדינים הנמצאים בכל הפוסקים, חדשים גם ישנים, עם מקומות מושבותם בחצריהם ובטירותם, בתלמוד בבלי ובתלמוד ירושלמי ובתוספתא, בספרא ובסיפרי, במכילתא ודברי המפרשים והפוסקים ובעלי התשובות, חדשים גם ישנים. ונתבאר שם כל דין ודין באר היטב, דבר דבור על אופניו, וארמון על משפטו ישב, תלוי עליו כל שלטי הגיבורים, אנשי השם אשר מעולם.‏
>
> ראיתי אני בלבי, כי טוב ללקוט שושני ספירי אמריו בדרך קצרה ולשון צח וכולל, יפה ונעים, למען תהיה תורת ה' תמימה שגורה בפי כל איש ישראל. כי כאשר ישאלו לתלמיד חכם דבר הלכה, לא יגמגם בה, אלא יאמר לחכמה אחותי את, כשם שברור לו שאחותו אסורה לו כך יהיה ברור לו כל דין שישאל עליו הלכה למעשה, בהיותו שגור בפיו ספר זה הבנוי לתלפיות, תל שהכל פונים בו, לחלקו לחלקים שלושים, ללמוד בו בכל יום חלק, ונמצא שבכל חודש הוא חוזר תלמודו, ויאמר עליו אשרי מי שבא לכאן ותלמודו בידו:‏
>
> זאת ועוד, התלמידים הקטנים יהגו תמיד וישננו לשונו על פה, ותהיה גירסא דינקותא מסודרת בפיהם מקטנותם הלכה למעשה, וגם כי יזקינו לא יסורו ממנה. והמשכילים יזהירו כזוהר הרקיע, בהניח להם מעצבם ומיגיע כפם, ישעשעו נפשם בהגותם בספר זה, אשר כלו מחמדים, הלכה פסוקה, באין אומר ואין דברים.‏
>
> וקראתי שם ספר זה שלחן ערוך, כי בו ימצא ההוגה כל מינין, מטעמים ערוכים בכל ושמורים, סדורים וברורים. ומובטח אני בחסד עליון, כי על ידי ספר זה תמלא הארץ דעה את ה' הקטנים עם הגדולים, תלמיד עם מבין, חכם חרשים ונבון לחש. ובכן אפרוש כפי אל ה', יעזרני על דבר כבוד שמו, להיות ממצדיקי הרבים, ויזכני החל וגמור להיות מסודר בהלכתו, מתוקן ומקובל וטוב ויפה. והנני מתחיל לעשות כאשר יעדתי וה' יהיה בעזרי:‏

Comment: This just pushes the question. What if they were left out of the Beis Yosef also?

Comment: @DonielF - you'd first have to find a case of that happening. ("That" being a Halacha mentioned in the Rambam, Rif or Rosh that the Bet Yosef ignores.) As far as I can tell the Bet Yosef is comprehensive, to say the least. (But after many years, I'm noway near finished.)